# How to import Enterprise URL Rewrites in 1.13?

Tags: magento-enterprise, ee-1.13, url-rewrite, enterprise-1.13

We recently migrated from a proprietary shopping cart to Magento Enterprise.

Currently we are using a custom module to redirect the old product URL's to the new Magento product URL's.

However, I am looking to move on from this front-end controller that handles this logic, to importing them as URL rewrite rules.

There seems to be a lot of documentation for creating a URL rewrite url in community edition, which uses the deprecated `core_url_rewrite` table.

Previously, you would do something like:

```
$results = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
    ->setIsSystem(0)
    ->setOptions('RP')
    ->setIdPath($legacy_url)
    ->setRequestPath($legacy_url)
    ->setTargetPath($url)
    ->setDescription('legacy product id '.$legacy_id)
    ->save();
```

However, in Enterprise 1.13, the model I think I should be using is: `enterprise_urlrewrite/url_rewrite`

Can someone advise on how to do the equivalent? I can't seem to get it to show up in the admin, even after doing a reindex.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Firsly the model is now `Enterprise_UrlRewrite_Model_Url_Rewrite`:

```
Mage::getModel('enterprise_urlrewrite/url_rewrite');
```

Secondly the options have changed slightly to.

**Options**

```
store_id,
identifier
target_path
options
description,
category_id
product_id
```

*Note: category and product id are optional only for category and product rewrites*

So assuming that your code is not for product or category rewrites:

```
$results = Mage::getModel('enterprise_urlrewrite/url_rewrite')
    ->setStoreId($store_id)
    ->setOptions('RP')
    ->setIdentifier($legacy_url)
    ->setTargetPath($url)
    ->setDescription('legacy product id '.$legacy_id)
    ->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue, creating custom rewrites (redirects) in Magento 1.13.
I only saw them in the admin when I addressed the redirect model rather than url_rewrite.

Here is a snippet of what I was using to set redirects on save of my custom entity.

```
//check for existing redirect
$redirect = Mage::getModel('enterprise_urlrewrite/redirect')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('target_path', $target_path)
    ->getFirstItem();

if(!$redirect->getId()){
    Mage::Log('no such redirect');
    $redirect = Mage::getModel('enterprise_urlrewrite/redirect');
}

$redirect
    ->setStoreId($store_id)
    ->setOptions('')
    ->setIdentifier($request_path)
    ->setTargetPath($target_path)
    ->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct class to use is Enterprise_UrlRewrite_Model_Redirect, so mtopping was right.
However I wouldn't use target_path to check if a rewrite exists as the field itself is not unique, request_path is (hence the column name is 'identifier). Here is what I would do:

```
Mage::getModel('enterprise_urlrewrite/redirect')->load($aRedirect['request_path'], 'identifier')
                ->setStoreId($iDefaultStoreId)
                ->setOptions('RP')
                ->setIdentifier($aRedirect['request_path'])
                ->setTargetPath($aRedirect['target_path'])
                ->setDescription('Redirect from old site')
                ->save();
```

That is, assuming you havea single store. For multistores you will have to use collection load. similar to what mtopping suggested but with extra addFieldToFilter for store id.